# Short exact sequence and Loewy length

Tags: representation-theory

Let $0\rightarrow L \rightarrow M\rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence in $mod A$, where $A$ is an artin algebra, and $mod A$ denotes the right finitely generated module category.

Question:
how to prove the following equality
$$\ell\ell (M)\leq \ell\ell(L)+\ell\ell(N).$$
Here, $\ell\ell(X)$ denotes the Loewy length of $X\in mod A.$

Comment: Please leave a comment to the question instead of editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $J$ denote the Jacobson radical of $A$. By the isomorphism theorem, we have
$$ (M/L)J^{\ell\ell(N)} \cong NJ^{\ell\ell(N)} = 0. $$
This implies 
$$ MJ^{\ell\ell(L)+\ell\ell(N)} = (MJ^{\ell\ell(N)}) J^{\ell\ell(L)} \leq LJ^{\ell\ell(L)} = 0,$$
which yields 
$$ \ell\ell(M) \le \ell\ell(L) + \ell\ell(N).$$

Comment: How to get that $(MJ^{\ell\ell(N)}) J^{\ell\ell(L)} \leq LJ^{\ell\ell(L)}$ ?

Comment: By $(M/L)J^{\ell\ell(N)} = 0$, i.e., $MJ^{\ell\ell(N)} \le L$.